# Changing the infoWindow when using google directions

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am currently using googles directions API, it works fine, and plots 8 waypoints onto my map with the route using this line of code:

```
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
```

However, each marks, when clicked, shows up an info window with the address of the waypoint. Is there a way to change the content of these infowindows?

Thanks in advance, James.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the {suppressInfoWindows: true} option to the [DirectionsRenderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions), add a click listener to the map to display what you want in an InfoWindow.  You may want to use {suppressMarkers:true} and create your own Markers so you can attach the click listener to the marker.

[Example with custom markers](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_iconsC.html) (more complicated than you need, but it shows how to create custom markers with infowindows)

[Example with custom markers and a waypoint](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypointsE.html)